# Why repeat the formula for how much flour?

Tags: pinchas

In the course of Parshat Pinchas (the relevant section is Bamidbar 28-29), where the sacrifices for each day are discussed, it frequently says that for a bull, the mincha is 3 tenths of an ephah, for a goat, 2 tenths, and for a sheep 1 tenth.  For example, it says this in Bamidbar 28:12-13 about Rosh Chodesh and again in verses 20-21 about Pesach, and in verses 28-29 about Shavuot.  This pattern continues into the next chapter with Rosh Hashana, Yom Kippur and Sukkot.

Why list this every time?  Why not give the formula once at the beginning and rely on that, as it does in the case of Sukkot and Shmini Atzeret?  Or, since for any particular holiday it just said how many sheep, goats & lambs, say "and 12 tenths of ephah of flour" or whatnot, as it does in the case of the daily tamid and Shabbat?  Does the fact that both the tamid & Shabbat's musaf consist of only a single species account for this difference?

Comment: Could it be the same reason the Karbanos of the Nesiim were repeated (see end of Naso) - to emphasize the uniqueness of the different karbanos?

Comment: @DonielF so there is a pesach reason why a bull gets 3 esronim and so on, and then a sukkot reason, and so on for each yomtov?  Not a crazy idea, just novel.

Comment: And that's why I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ramban in 28:7](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=4&perek=28&mefaresh=ramban) answers this question.

> הזכיר הכתוב בתמיד ובראשי חדשיכם שיעור הסלת במנחה ושיעור היין בנסכים, אבל בשבת ובחג המצוות ובשבועות ובראש השנה וביום הכיפורים ובראשון של חג הסוכות הזכיר שיעור המנחה ולא הזכיר שיעור הנסכים. ‏
> והטעם בזה, כי אף על פי שציוה בפרשת הנסכים (לעיל טו): בשיעורי המנחה והנסכים לפר ולאיל ולכבשים בנדרים ונדבות ובמועדים (שם פסוק ג), **מצינו מנחה כפולה לכבש העומר** (ויקרא כג יג), **וביום העצרת שתים שני עשרונים חמץ** (שם פסוק יז), **וכן בקרבן התודה** (שם ז יב יג), **והם מנחה, ולכך הוצרך הכתוב לפרש בכל המועדות שלא תשתנה בהם המנחה כאשר נשתנית באלו.** אבל הנסכים לא נשתנו לעולם, לפיכך הזכיר אותם בתחילה בתמיד, ולא הזכירם אחרי כן בשבת, וחזר והזכירם בראש חדש להזכיר גם נסכי הפר והאלים, ואחר כך לא הוצרך להזכירם כלל. והזכיר ביום הראשון של סוכות שיעור המנחה (להלן כט יד), ולא הוצרך עוד להזכיר באותו החג אלא "מנחתם ונסכיהם במספרם כמשפטם", כלומר כמשפטם ביום הראשון הנזכר:‏

The reason the flour is repeated almost everywhere is because thrice we find a different quantity of flour.

The lamb brought with the Omer had a double Mincha, and the Shavuoth sacrifices and Todah had unusual Mincha quantities.

On Shabbat the Mincha is not explicitly mentioned since the Shabbat Mussaf was just a doubled-daily sacrifice, so it's "*obvious*" how much to bring, as opposed to a regular Mussaf that has a (seemingly random) number of animals.

Since the Sukkoth ones are a sequence, it's abbreviated as "their Mincha" to be understood referring to the first day where it's mentioned.